# Align fragment on bottom of screen

Tags: android, user-interface

Hi I have a linear layout with a fragment widget placed inside it. I'm trying get the fragment to show up on the bottom of the screen. The page may be scrollable in the future so I want it anchored on the bottom of the screen always. How can I achieve this?

Comment: then whats the issue?

Comment: ohh great i deserve upvotes and accept answer remark  :P isnt it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use `RelativeLayout`. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_fragment" >
    </ScrollView>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bottom_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    </fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this with constraint layout use the line below.

> app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_16dp">
        //UI Components..
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It looks like bottom_sheet_fragment. This is the root tag of xml file. I say to ConstraintLayout, its bottom should stay at the parents(activity) bottom, and height attribute should wrap the other UI components inside the fragment, then it sticks to the parent bottom of the screen.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: this answer is a little vague, please explain this more